# Make side-by-side markdown preview scroll with its editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, markdown

I've got a Markdown editor on the left side and its HTML preview on the right side.

How do I make the preview scroll to the same location as the editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Remarkable library](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable) use a complex scroll sync for the demo : https://github.com/jonschlinkert/remarkable/blob/dev/demo/assets/index.js#L213

Comment: I've implemented the same approach for [PanWriter](https://panwriter.com). Hopefully a bit more understandable and more commented. See [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54076421/214446)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var $elements = $('textarea');

var sync = function(e){
    var $other = $elements.not(this).off('scroll'), other = $other.get(0);
    var percentage = this.scrollTop / (this.scrollHeight - this.offsetHeight);
    other.scrollTop = percentage * (other.scrollHeight - other.offsetHeight);
    setTimeout( function(){ $other.on('scroll', sync ); },10);
}

$elements.on( 'scroll', sync);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b75KZ/5/

Although, I'm not sure if it would be a `textarea` that you'd want on the right, perhaps a `div` to show the rendered html?

If so just change the element in the html and the selector in the jQuery to `var $elements = $('textarea, div#html');` and ensure you have the `id` attribute set for the `div`.

Also, if you have multiple `textarea`s on the page and want to be more specific just change the selector to `var $elements = $('textarea#markdown, div#html');` and update the markup accordingly, e.g.

```
<textarea id="markdown">...</textarea>
<div id="html">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you linked to just align the scrollbars to the same height, it does not seem to do any intelligent matching of elements.

So a good start is just to align scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Are there more intelligent approaches to this? This fails to easily on image-heavy documents.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this for [PanWriter](https://panwriter.com/).

The gist from [this commit](https://github.com/mb21/panwriter/commit/674bfa992efd4e36a24b3e5c63001bda2767da8f#diff-2a5ab40416e08983feff8912dfe9a9a1R50):

```
var editor = ... // a CodeMirror editor instance
var frameWindow = document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow; // my preview frame
var scrollMap;

editor.on("scroll", function() {
  if (!scrollMap) {
    buildScrollMap(editor, 10);
  }
  frameWindow.scrollTo(0, scrollMap[scrollTop]);
});

function buildScrollMap(editor, editorOffset) {
  // scrollMap maps source-editor-line-offsets to preview-element-offsets
  // (offset is the number of vertical pixels from the top)
  scrollMap = [];
  scrollMap[0] = 0;

  // lineOffsets[i] holds top-offset of line i in the source editor
  var lineOffsets = [undefined, 0]
    , knownLineOffsets = []
    , offsetSum = 0
    ;
  editor.eachLine( function(line) {
    offsetSum += line.height;
    lineOffsets.push(offsetSum);
  });

  var lastEl;
  frameWindow.document.querySelectorAll('body > [data-source-line]').forEach( function(el){
    // for each element in the preview with source annotation
    var line = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-source-line'), 10)
      , lineOffset = lineOffsets[line]
      ;
    // fill in the target offset for the corresponding editor line
    scrollMap[lineOffset] = el.offsetTop - editorOffset;
    knownLineOffsets.push(lineOffset)

    lastEl = el;
  });
  if (lastEl) {
    scrollMap[offsetSum] = lastEl.offsetTop + lastEl.offsetHeight;
    knownLineOffsets.push(offsetSum);
  }

  // fill in the blanks by interpolating between the two closest known line offsets
  var j = 0;
  for (var i=1; i < offsetSum; i++) {
    if (scrollMap[i] === undefined) {
      var a = knownLineOffsets[j]
        , b = knownLineOffsets[j + 1]
        ;
      scrollMap[i] = Math.round(( scrollMap[b]*(i - a) + scrollMap[a]*(b - i) ) / (b - a));
    } else {
      j++;
    }
  }
}
```

For this to work, you need source-line annotations on your HTML output (use e.g. [markdown-it-source-map](https://github.com/tylingsoft/markdown-it-source-map#markdown-it-source-map)).

Of course, you'll also have to do it the other way around (when you scroll the preview, make the editor scroll) and look out for edge-cases/offset, depending on your layout. But this is the basic algorithm.

And you probably want to wrap this in something like [_.throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle).